# Computing the limit of an integral (Derivatives of Integrals)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, continuity

Assuming that $f(x)$ is continuous in the neighborhood of $a$, compute

$$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{x}{x-a} \int_a^x f(t)dt $$

Comment: Hints: What is the derivative of $x \mapsto \int_a^x f(t) dx$? What is the definition of the derivative of a function at $a$?

Comment: Isn't it just f(x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Derivatives of Integrals always keep this formula in your mind
$$\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)dt = F(h(x))-F(g(x))$$
in which $\dfrac{d F(t)}{dt} = f(t)$.

So we can easily have
$$\dfrac{d \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)dt}{dx} = \dfrac{d (F(h(x))-F(g(x)))}{dx}=f(h(x))h'(x) - f(g(x))g'(x).$$

So back to your question. In this question we have an indeterminate form of type $0\over0$ so we can easily apply the *L’Hospital’s Rule*. So we have
$$ \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{x \times \int_a^x f(t)dt}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{(1 \times \int_a^x f(t)dt) + (f(x) \times x)}{1} $$

so

$$=\lim_{x \to a}\int_a^x f(t)dt + \lim_{x \to a}xf(x) = af(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x}{x-a} \int_a^x f(t)dt =\lim_{x \to a} x\frac{ \int_a^x f(t)dt-0}{x-a}=\lim_{x \to a} x\lim_{x \to a} \frac{ \int_a^x f(t)dt-0}{x-a}$$